# Is it safe to use memcpy with vectors of Eigen types?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a program that internally handles point clouds as vectors of Eigen objects:

```
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f> point_cloud;
```

This program needs to convert these point clouds into a different format for serialization. Here is the format of this other type:

```
struct Point32 {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
};
std::vector<Point32> point_cloud_other;
```

The question is, is it guaranteed to be safe to use memcpy to copy over the Eigen point clouds on x86 / x86_64 computers? By "safe" I'm referring specifically to the integrity of the data. That is, is it safe to do this without corrupting the point cloud:

```
point_cloud_other.resize(point_cloud.size());
memcpy(point_cloud_other.data(), point_cloud.data(), 
       point_cloud.size() * sizeof(Eigen::Vector3f));
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `memcpy`? Use `std::copy` or `std::copy_n`, it will always do the right thing (which could be calling `memcpy` internally if the object being copied is POD)

Comment: I'd say "No", but it might be better qualified than a gut reaction if there was some indication of what an `Eigen::Vector3f` looked like. If your `Point32` was a synonym for `Eigen::Vector3f`, then maybe...but it still isn't exactly going to be type-safe C++ programming.

Answer (score 0):

The STL vector class guarantees that its data will be stored in a single contiguous array, so memcpy() should be safe as long as the vector you are copying into is at least as large as the one you are copying from.

That said, it would be better and less error-prone to use vector methods or operators to do what you want, rather than trying to "go behind its back" with memcpy().  If you're hoping that memcpy() will perform better, I think you will find that it doesn't make any difference (although you could measure to verify that).

Comment: But `memcpy`ing non-POD is undefined behavior?